# Which algorithm is used behind the matplotlib.path

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to understand the mathematical method/logic/algorithm which works behind the matplotlib function matplotlib.path and then its further extension to check point within a polygon using.

path=matplotlib.path.Path(polygon)
inside = path.contains_point(points)

I want to know which mathematical routine is coded at the back-end of these commands.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you take a look at https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/path_api.html? It specifies some algorithms, http://www.spaceroots.org/documents/ellipse/index.html, https://www.tinaja.com/glib/ellipse4.pdf. The source code also has some info: https://matplotlib.org/stable/_modules/matplotlib/path.html#Path

Comment: You might also be interested in [Wikipedia's point in polygon article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon)